# Connect multiple Arduinos to ESP32's RTC?

Tags: esp8266, esp32, rtc

> Depending on usage frequency, may get the occasional collision where
> both test for availability at the same time - if occurring too
> frequently, maybe add something simple like one arduino only does time
> updates on even seconds, the other on odd seconds.

https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=64049.0

I need events executed in the multiple receiving Arduino's to occur in sync (simultaneously). Is there a library or something, probably using the ESP32's RTC, to ensure events occur in sync?

Example system:

- ESP32 sender/master
- Arduino1 receiver controlling LEDs (Christmas lights)
- Arduino2 receiver controlling stepper motors (Mary figure)
- Arduino3 receiver controlling stepper motors (Joseph figure)

The issue is that they are sent data at different times by the user.

Say, the user selects settings for Mary. That data is sent to the ESP32, and then that data is sent to all the Arduinos, but only "gets into" the MaryArduino.

Then, the user selects settings for the lights. That data is sent to the ESP32, and then data is sent to all the Arduinos, but only "gets into the LightsAruino.

Etc.

However, I need everything to start at the same time.

The data is not simultaneously sent. It is sent one after the other, as slow as the user selects their settings. However, the sequence of events must simultaneously occur.

Comment: moving an actuator, turning on a light, running a stepper motor a number of steps, etc.

Comment: why do the light and actuator have to be synchronized? ... what is their purpose?

Comment: Events need to happen at specific times: Think of a light show synchronized to music.

Comment: I said, "events executed in the receiving Arduino_>>_'s_<<_" but I edited the post with multiple in again (beside already being in the title).

Comment: You state: "I need events executed in the multiple receiving Arduino's to occur in sync". What is the tolerance you can allow, this will have a big impact on the plausibility and cost of the design. Is your software designed to be that way and do you know how many clock cycles each remote will do before performing the task, they must be the same to be fully in sync. If not how do you compensate for this difference and how do you detect an error.

Comment: light synchronized to music is not an example of simultaneous events, as far as the microcontroller is concerned  ... it only has to look synchronized to a human ... a microcontroller can go on vacation between two events and the two events would still look simultaneous to a human

Comment: Lights synchronized to music IS an example of simultaneous events since they are both done by different Arduino's (as that's how it's meaningfully related to the question asked).

Comment: @Gil No software has been designed. That's why I'm looking into this question. The idea is to use the ESP32's RTC connected to multiple receiving Arduinos. The ESP is the sender. Say three are connected. All three would be going off the ESP32's RTC.

Comment: it is unckear what the overall system consists of .... perhaps the simplest solution is to have a hardware clock signal that connects all of the arduinos

Comment: So gather the data from the sender, and hold until a digital signal is sent? E.g., lights get song, figure1 gets sequence of movements, then figure2 gets sequence of movements. Once the last event happens, wait part of a second and send a digital HIGH signal. And just have a simple if-statement waiting for that signal?

Comment: use serial, the ESP32 has 3 of them, and capability to do many more. the AVRs do stuff when told to over serial. the ESP32 tells them what to do over serial. Even though on a microscopic level the messages will be staggered by microseconds, it won't make a hill of beans difference to a light show, or even most scientific experiments.

Comment: I'm using one serial connection to send the commands to all the Arduinos (10-30). @dandavis Are you suggesting that same serial connection be used OR 10-30 additional serial out? The latter isn't really possible as you know.

Comment: @adamaero You can connect serial in parallel, ironically. if your high-level protocol allows all nodes to get the same broadcast, typically by each having an ID/tag it's "interested" in ala wifi/i2c, there's no real limit. If each line has to transmit different messages, then you can still easily do a dozen or two with an ESP32, since you only need TXs and it has a whole dang bunch of pins ;)

Comment: Yes, I have each Arduino addressed already: `if(charArr1[0] == motionHead) strcpy(str2, charArr1);` They are all being sent the same data, but only each one is receiving their specific data.

Comment: then just wire all the slave RXs together to the master's TX, and then send away. With a message format like "MARY=1;RED=1", at 57k baud, mary and the red light will turn on at the same time (fraction of a ms), even to a high-speed camera, much less a human.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120058/discussion-between-adamaero-and-dandavis).

Comment: Try this link for a paper by Autosar Specification of Time Synchronization over CAN: https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/4-3/AUTOSAR_SWS_TimeSyncOverCAN.pdf It has a lot of good information.

Answer (score 1):

Give the master a single signal wire that is connected to all of the slaves and that signal LOW while the master sends commands to each slave. Let each of the slave Arduinos simply store its message but not act on it while the signal wire is LOW.

When the slaves are supposed to start, raise the signal level to HIGH. Each slave Arduino now executes whatever command it had been sent. The RTC now only needs to be connected to the Master, which controls all of the timing.